# Agrupar 2 Arrays

Tags: arraylist, kotlin

Como puedo agrupar estos arrays en una sola lista?

```
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<DetPartModel1>, response: Response<DetPartModel1>) {

                val golLocal = (response.body()!!.golesLocal)
                val golVisi = (response.body()!!.golesVisitante)

val list = response.body()!!.golesLocal!! + response.body()!!.golesVisitante!!

                Rv_DetLocal.adapter = DetLocalAdapter(list as List<DetPartModel1>)
```

El adaptador:

```
class DetLocalAdapter(private val det_partido: List<DetPartModel1> ): RecyclerView.Adapter<DetLocalAdapter.TiempoViewHolder>() {

private var context: Context? = null

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): TiempoViewHolder {
    val layoutInflate = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        .inflate(R.layout.partido_goles_row, parent, false)

    context = parent.context

    return DetLocalAdapter.TiempoViewHolder(layoutInflate)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: TiempoViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val itemDetPart = det_partido[position]
    holder.bindTiempo(itemDetPart)

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener{

        val bundle = Bundle()
        bundle.putString(Constants.ID_JUG, itemDetPart.golesLocal !![0].idJugador)
        context!!.startActivity(Intent(context, DetPlantilla::class.java).putExtras(bundle))
    }
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return det_partido.size
}

class TiempoViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    fun bindTiempo(plantillaModel2: DetPartModel1){

        itemView.tv_JugadorLocal.text = plantillaModel2.golesLocal!!.get(0).nombreLocal + "\n Minuto: " + plantillaModel2.golesLocal!!.get(0).nombreLocal
        itemView.tv_JugadorVisi.text = plantillaModel2.golesVisitante!!.get(0).nombreVisi + "\n Minuto: " + plantillaModel2.golesVisitante!!.get(0).nombreVisi

        Picasso.get()
            .load("https://ffcv.es/ncompeticiones/img/jugadores/" + plantillaModel2.golesLocal!!.get(0)!!.idJugador + ".jpeg")
            .fit()
            .into(itemView.civ_jugadorLocal)
    }
}
```

}

> java.lang.ClassCastException: com.myapplication.Jornadas.DetPartidos.DetLocalModel cannot be cast to com.myapplication.Jornadas.DetPartidos.DetPartModel1
>           at com.myapplication.Jornadas.DetPartidos.DetLocalAdapter.onBindViewHolder(DetLocalAdapter.kt:34)
>           at com.myapplication.Jornadas.DetPartidos.DetLocalAdapter.onBindViewHolder(DetLocalAdapter.kt:20)

Linea 20:

```
class DetLocalAdapter(private val det_partido: List<DetPartModel1> ): RecyclerView.Adapter<DetLocalAdapter.TiempoViewHolder>() {
```

Linea 34:

```
val itemDetPart = det_partido[position]
```

Comment: ¿Qué arrays? ¿Los que están dentro de la variable `list`?

Comment: Estos:  val golLocal = (response.body()!!.golesLocal)
val golVisi = (response.body()!!.golesVisitante)

Comment: Si la  variable list

Answer (score 2):

En kotlin todos los arrays y listas tienen el operador `plus` sobreescrito de tal manera que se concatenan, por lo que esto:

```
// asumiendo que golesLocal y golesVisitante son dos arrays, o listas
list = response.body()!!.golesLocal + response.body()!!.golesVisitante
```

Debería concatenarlos en una sola lista.

Comment: post1 editado con el adaptador y el error

Comment: Y como la paso al adaptador?, porque no lo consigo

Comment: Si los concatena y en el debug me sale correctamente, pero no se como pasarlo al adaptador y que me lo muestre en el recyclerView

Comment: @RafelC.F Aunque no tiene que ver con la pregunta parece que estás intentando castear una lista de un tipo a otra de otro tipo, y esos dos son incompatibles.

Comment: Las listas son iguales, un array golesLocal y el otro, golesVisitante, en el mismo json, los mismos nombres para los strings, a la noche pongo la URL del json

Comment: este es el json *https://www.ffcv.es/ncompeticiones/server.php?action=getActa&tmp=2018/2019&jor=19&cmp=328&idl=0201045201&idv=0201411651&id=22554415* no entiendo por que no me sale. Te enviaria todos los archivos por mail, llevo mas de un mes con esto y nada no lo consigo.

Comment: asi, si me pasan pero ¿como diferencio los locales de los visitantes, osea, los locales a la izquierda y los visitantes a la derecha, habra que pasarlos como 2 listas y es lo que no me sale.

Comment: A ver, si concatenas los arrays y son del mismo tipo, entonces claro que no lo vas a poder diferenciar. En vez de eso, ¿or qué no te creas una clase que contenga ambos arrays y es esa clase la que pasas? En todo caso esto se está yendo de madre. Empezó en cómo concatenar arrays y ahora preguntas por otra cosa totalmente distinta. ¿Por qué no formulas otra pregunta, que ponga bien claro qué es lo que quieres y qué te pasa?